# How should we tag Mount And Blade: Napoleonic Wars?

Tags: discussion, tags

The new DLC for Mount and Blade Warband, Napoleonic Wars, is out. But the full name, 
[mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars) is obviously too long for the character limit, as is just [mount-and-blade-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-napoleonic-wars).

My suggestions for tagging it would be:

- [m-and-b-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-b-napoleonic-wars): Just under the limit, but,despite the use of M&B in place of Mount and Blade, the game name may not be obvious
- [mount-and-blade-nw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-nw): We use the full game name, and the abbreviation NW is often used in the community to replace Napoleonic Wars, for example in server names.

Comment: how is NW btw, not sure if I want to pick it up at some point considering the fiasco that's F&S :P

Comment: WTB tag character limit increase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The tag name is now [mount-and-blade-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-napoleonic-wars).**

Since the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and retagged two questions with the full title.

The official title, [mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars) (39), would require an additional increase in tag length, which I don't see happening anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fond of keeping the prefix without abbreviation, and relying on autocomplete to to help with finding the actual tag.

So I think [mount-and-blade-nw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-nw) is okay, as long as the tag wiki excerpt contains the full name.

Comment: Regardless of which tag we keep as canonical, it's probably going to be best to synonimize all relevant options so that autocomplete works properly. For the canonical, worry more about SEO and readability along the questions list or in the title element.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessarily to put the name of the DLC directly in "game name" tag?

When I wan't to follow some game I follow the original "game name" tag so that particular game is highlighted on main screen.For me it doesn't really matter if the game is for PC,XboX or what DLC I use those tags just as additional question info.

If tag is formatted as **fallout-3-the-pitt** and someone is to follow complete Fallout 3 series he would than have to follow 5 different name tags for every DLC.

If tag is formatted as **fallout-3** and **the-pitt** someone who wants to follow just specific area of a game can still follow it just with that secondary tag.

There is also the issue of name length,longer the name more abbreviations it needs which is a bad thing since everyone makes their own abbreviations.

Comment: +1, I think this is probably the best solution unless we need to disambiguate a DLC that shares a name with another game.

Comment: hm that would make some problems,but still it would be rare especially since game companies are trying to avoid all possible copyright lawsuits.

Comment: FWIW, you can use wildcards for favorite tags, so you could follow `fallout-3*` and then everything tagged starting with `fallout-3` would show up as favorited, rather than having to follow X amount of separate tags.

Comment: Adding wildcards is even more clicking than just following few games :/